# CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo, kCGWindowLayer and window level

Tags: macos, window, layer, quartz-graphics

The `CGWindowLevel.h` file defines the constants that are used to set the window level and the largest value that can be used as window level is 20. But, if you retrieve the window list using the call `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo`, you can observe that the value of `kCGWindowLayer` is more than 20 (25, 103 etc).

Aren't kCGWindowLayer and window level same? 
If they are not same, how do I get the window level for the windows that are obtained using `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo`?
If they are same, why do we get value >20?

Answer (score 6):

It appears that `kCGWindowLayer` does refer to a window level, though I haven't found any documentation saying that.

You seem to think that window levels can be at most 20 because of the enumeration from `kCGBaseWindowLevelKey` to `kCGAssistiveTechHighWindowLevelKey`, that last one having the value 20.  But these are not window levels, they are keys that can be used to look up window levels using `CGWindowLevelForKey`.  For example, `kCGStatusWindowLevelKey` has the value 9, but `kCGStatusWindowLevel` is defined as `CGWindowLevelForKey(kCGStatusWindowLevelKey)`, and the value of that turns out to be 25.

Answer (score 2):

No. kCGWindowLayer and window level are not same. You cannot get window level directly. But you can do a trick as below.

```
        CFArrayRef windowArray = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID);
        NSMutableArray *windowsInMap = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:64];
        NSArray*  windows = (NSArray*)CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID);
        NSUInteger count = [windows count];
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            NSDictionary*   nswindowsdescription = [windows objectAtIndex:i];
            NSNumber* windowid = (NSNumber*)[nswindowsdescription objectForKey:@"kCGWindowNumber"];
            if(windowid)
            {
                       // Entried will be in front to back order.
            }
        }
        CFRelease(windowArray);
```

Comment: What exactly the `kCGWindowLayer` is. In the [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CGWindow_Reference/Constants/Constants.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kCGWindowLayer), it only says `kCGWindowLayer` is the **window layer number** , no explanation about window layer number.

Comment: MacGeek, you seem to be thinking that window level means an index in front to back order, but that's not what e.g. `-[NSWindow level]` is about.